# "gcc -DSOMENAME"; "SOMENAME" not getting defined

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to execute a PintOS command `pintos -f` (do not worry if you are not familiar with PintOS). Internally, `init.c` program is called, whose `parse_options()` function handles the command line arguments passed. Below is the relevant snippet of init.c

```
static char **
parse_options (char **argv) 
{
   for (; *argv != NULL && **argv == '-'; argv++)
   {
      char *save_ptr;
      char *name = strtok_r (*argv, "=", &save_ptr); //fn to tokenise the string
      char *value = strtok_r (NULL, "", &save_ptr);
      if (!strcmp (name, "-h"))
        usage ();
      else if (!strcmp (name, "-q"))
        power_off_when_done = true;
      else if (!strcmp (name, "-r"))
        reboot_when_done = true;
      /*$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$*/

      #ifdef FILESYS
      else if (!strcmp (name, "-f"))
        format_filesys = true;
      #endif

      /*$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$*/
      else if (!strcmp (name, "-rs"))
        random_init (atoi (value));
      else if (!strcmp (name, "-mlfqs"))
        thread_mlfqs = true;
      #ifdef USERPROG
      else if (!strcmp (name, "-ul"))
        user_page_limit = atoi (value);
      #endif
      else
        PANIC ("unknown option `%s' (use -h for help)", name);
   }
   return argv;
}
```

As per the code inside the `$$$$` section, the `-f` option passed will be processed only if FILESYS is defined.

On executing `make`, the following command is executed

```
gcc -m32 -c ../../threads/init.c -o threads/init.o -g -msoft-float -O -fno-stack-    protector -nostdinc -I../.. -I../../lib -I../../lib/kernel -Wall -W -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wsystem-headers -DUSERPROG -DFILESYS -MMD -MF threads/init.d
```

Here, -DUSERPROG and -DFILESYS options are provided to define FILESYS and USERPROG, so that the relevant sections of the code can be executed. However, somehow, FILESYS is not getting defined, as evident from the following output of `pintos -f` command

```
Kernel command line: -f
Kernel PANIC at ../../threads/init.c:261 in parse_options(): unknown option `-f' (use -h for help)
```

Several other tests confirm that FILESYS not getting defined IS the issue. I checked the gcc syntax and even wrote the following Dummy program to check the -DNAME option with gcc.

DummyProg.c

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main()
{
#ifdef CHECK 
    printf("WORKING\n");
#endif
return 0;
}
```

With `gcc -DCHECK DummyProg.c` and `./a.out`, WORKING was displayed on the screen, conforming the validity of syntax etc. The gcc version I am using is **gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3**

Could someone please point how to resolve this issue.

Comment: So you see that `-DSOMETHING` is not the issue. How about you reduce your problem iteratively until the error disolves? Did you try a different identifier?

Comment: Whenever I've got a problem like that I just write some garbage into one of the lines that should be included. That way it's quite easy to determine whether the problem is the definition/macro or some actual code in there. E.g. if this causes a code error, you know your `#ifdef` works, but there's some other problem with code itself.

Comment: If you really used `-DSOMENAME, SOMEOTHERNAME` then it will not work as you need `-DSOMENAME -DSOMEOTHERNAME`

Comment: @RedX you misread the title. It is short for "if i compile with "gcc -DS", "S" is not defined. Read the question to see that he compiles correctly

Comment: @RedX oh no! You misinterpreted me. What I am trying to say is that I used gcc -DSOMENAME. But SOMENAME was not getting defined. Bytheway, it seems now that -DSOMENAME is not the issue. Most probably, it is working fine and there is some other issue in building init.c. Will update the status after some more debugging.

Comment: what i find useful in such situations (and less verbose than running `cpp`/`gcc -E`) is to add `#warning USERPROG` directives into the ifdef'ed code: during compilation your gcc will spit out warnings if they are in an enabled code segment.

Comment: Perhaps the `FILESYS` macro is dynamically determined by other macros/compiler features/etc, and as such, the build system is not expecting to use `-DFILESYS`, but instead editing a `config.h` or something. In other words, maybe, even though you pass `-DFILESYS` on the command line, something in a header file is helpfully undefining it for you...

Answer (score 1):

The compiler can help you understand this; the trick is to capture the proprocessed code *with the `#define` statements left in*:

```
gcc -E -dD ...blah...
```

You have to remove the `-c` and `-o <outfile>` options from the compile command, but otherwise leave it unchanged, apart from adding the two new options.

`-E` tells it to do the preprocess step only, and output it to screen.

`-dD` tells it to leave in the `#define` and `#undef` directives.

My guess is that your code has a `#undef FILESYS` directive somewhere, and it's overriding your `-DFILESYS` option.

Answer (score 0):

To debug issues like this, run `gcc` with `-E`. This will just run the code through the preprocessor `cpp`. Look into the output file to see what the input of the C compiler would be after the post-processing step.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you are building the entire executable/library/...?

looking at the command that gets triggered when calling `make`, only a single file is compiled into an intermediate object file. no linking into the final binary happens.

so it guess that you are still using an outdated build. try going to the toplevel source directory and execute:

```
 make clean && make
```

Comment: This is only a part of the make's output, showing the gcc statement evoked on init.c by the make file. By debugging, I have figured out that somehow the init.c is not getting built correctly and the cause seems to be some conflicts/issues with other pintOS utilities. Still figuring it out. Thanks for the advice :)